# Kivy split label layout div sizes

Tags: python, layout, split, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently trying to implement a custom widget that can have two colors in its' text. It almost works but I have two questions, the first one is: why is there a gap between the green and red BoxLayout div (blackbar in the attached image)? The second is how can I make the split labels to have a width of one div instead of two?
I tried many things but nothing worked so far. Any suggestions/ideas are very appreciated! Thanks in advance

[Visualisation of my problem. Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVjy2.png)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Split>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    NormalLabel
    NormalLabel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size_hint:1,None
        TopHalfLabel
        BottomHalfLabel   
    NormalLabel
    NormalLabel          


<TopHalfLabel>:
    size_hint:1,None    
    markup:True
    text:"[color=#FF0000]How can I do this?[/color]"
    font_size:30
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.3  # Border color (red in this example)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        
<BottomHalfLabel>:
    size_hint:1,None
    markup:True
    text:"[color=#FFFF00]How can I do this?[/color]"
    font_size:30          
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.3  # Border color (red in this example)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<NormalLabel>:
    size_hint:1,None
    markup:True
    text:"[color=#FFFF00]How can I do this?[/color]"
    font_size:30          
    height: self.texture_size[1]#
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.3  # Border color (red in this example)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')
                    

class NormalLabel(Label):
    pass 

class TopHalfLabel(Label):
    def on_texture_size(self, instance, value):
        #self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, self.texture.height/2, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)
        self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, self.texture.height/2, self.texture.width, self.texture.height)
  

class BottomHalfLabel(Label):
    def on_texture_size(self, instance, value):
        #self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, 0, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)
        self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, -self.texture.height/2, self.texture.width, self.texture.height)

class Split(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):   
        return Split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine the style of a `Widget` by prefixing its `kv` rule with a `-`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#redefining-a-widget-s-style). So, I modified your `kv` rules like this:

```
<-TopHalfLabel>:
    size_hint:1,None    
    markup:True
    text:"[color=#FF0000]How can I do this?[/color]"
    font_size:30
    height: self.texture_size[1]/2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.3  # Border color (red in this example)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.new_texture
            size: self.texture_size[0], self.texture_size[1]/2
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1]/4)

<-BottomHalfLabel>:
    size_hint:1,None
    markup:True
    text:"[color=#FFFF00]How can I do this?[/color]"
    font_size:30          
    height: self.texture_size[1]/2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 0.3  # Border color (red in this example)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.new_texture
            size: self.texture_size[0], self.texture_size[1]/2
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1]/4)
```

The main changes are setting the `height` to half the texture height and the addition of the `canvas` section, which is based on the default `kv` for a `Label`, but uses a `new_texture` property that is defined by modified classes:

```
class TopHalfLabel(Label):
    new_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_texture_size(self, instance, value):
        # self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, self.texture.height/2, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)
        self.new_texture = self.texture.get_region(0, self.texture.height / 2, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)


class BottomHalfLabel(Label):
    new_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    def on_texture_size(self, instance, value):
        # self.texture = self.texture.get_region(0, 0, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)
        self.new_texture = self.texture.get_region(0, 0, self.texture.width, self.texture.height/2)
```

I also added a `height: self.minimum_height` in the containing `BoxLayout`:

```
<Split>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    NormalLabel
    NormalLabel
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size_hint:1,None
        height: self.minimum_height
        TopHalfLabel
        BottomHalfLabel   
    NormalLabel
    NormalLabel
```

I think this does what you want.